# SQL Error : column ambiguously defined with subquery

Tags: php, sql, oracle

I'm trying to make a paged display, I've had succes before  with this pattern, but this one doesn't work for some reason:

This works,

```
select e.data,e.onorar,d.data,d.suma 
from contract_j e 
join rata d on e.id_cj = d.id_cj 
join persoana l on l.id_p = e.id_avocat
```

but this doesnt

```
select * from (
select a.*, rownum as rnum from (

select e.data,e.onorar,d.data,d.suma 
from contract_j e 
join rata d on e.id_cj = d.id_cj 
join persoana l on l.id_p = e.id_avocat) a 

where rownum <= :maxrow) 
where rnum >= :minrow
```

It says column ambiguously defined at line 2

Why? I can't figure it out..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`data` column is in `SELECT` 2 times referring different tables in inner query, whereas in outer query it went ambiguous! So just add suitable alias in inner query to be unique

```
select * from (
select a.*, rownum as rnum from (

select e.data as e_data,e.onorar,d.data as d_data,d.suma 
from contract_j e 
join rata d on e.id_cj = d.id_cj 
join persoana l on l.id_p = e.id_avocat) a 

where rownum <= :maxrow) 
where rnum >= :minrow
```

Comment: how can I select only a.e_data rather than a.*?

Comment: @SaikatBiswas you can just replace `a.*` by `a.e_data`

Comment: In a similar example, it was not working.. anyway.. it is working.. thanks